# Oracle CASE WHEN Short-Circuit Return Expressions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which based on the type, I want to aggregate values using either the arithmetic mean - `AVG(value)` - or the geometric mean - `EXP(AVG(LN(value)))`. My attempt is with a `CASE WHEN` statement but the issue is that some values can be 0 which means the `LN(0)` part will fail.

```sql
WITH tbl AS
  (
     SELECT 0 as val, 'avg' as calc_type FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1 as val, 'geom_mean' FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT CASE WHEN max(calc_type) = 'avg' THEN AVG(val)
       ELSE EXP(AVG(LN(val))) END as res
FROM tbl
GROUP BY calc_type
```

> ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range

Based on [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm), it appears this is expected as the `return_exprs` are evaluated for type stability.

> For both simple and searched CASE expressions, all of the return_exprs must either have the same datatype (CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2, NUMBER, BINARY_FLOAT, or BINARY_DOUBLE) or must all have a numeric datatype.

While I could do a filter for each calculation type and then `UNION ALL` the results, it would be ideal to do it in one query as I have to join a lot of tables to get to this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle *does* process the `CASE` expressions in order.  Unfortunately, because the aggregation, it also needs to evaluate *all* the aggregation expressions before it gets around to the `CASE`.  And that is where the error is occurring.  Note:  I'm not sure where this is documented for Oracle, but I've seen the problem in other databases.

The solution is to use another `CASE` expression to avoid errors:

```
WITH tbl AS (
      SELECT 0 as val, 'avg' as calc_type FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 as val, 'geom_mean' FROM DUAL
     )
SELECT CASE WHEN max(calc_type) = 'avg' THEN AVG(val)
       ELSE EXP(AVG(LN(CASE WHEN val > 0 THEN val END))) END as res
FROM tbl
GROUP BY calc_type
```

Comment: Thanks! You are (of course) correct that non-aggregation allows Oracle to short-circuit the ```LN(0)``` issue. Definitely interesting. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cole . . . I would call tis a documentation bug.  However, the documentation is probably *technically* correct.  The *expressions* are not evaluated right away.  *Subexpressions* are evaluated -- because they need to be during the aggregation.  So, you get an error on a subexpression, even though the complete expression might never be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Since for LN to work, value must be greater than 0. How is this:

```
 WITH tbl AS
  (
     SELECT 0 as val, 'avg' as calc_type FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1 as val, 'geom_mean' FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT CASE WHEN max(calc_type) = 'avg' THEN AVG(val)
        WHEN max(calc_type) = 'geom_mean' AND val >0 THEN EXP(AVG(LN(val))) ELSE NULL END as res
FROM tbl
GROUP BY calc_type
```

Comment: The condition `AND val > 0`, as you have it outside any aggregate functions, will throw a syntax error, since `val` is not a `group by` expression. If you want to see how this is done correctly, look at Gordon Linoff's solution (which was posted before yours anyway).